# Extract xpath in postgres

Tags: postgresql, xpath

have a postgres query to extract xml , not able to provide the xpath correctly

```
select column1, xmlcolumn from tabla
```

`xmlcolumn` is of the type:

```
<tag1>
  <tag2>
    <tag3>test</tag3>
  </tag2>
</tag1>
```

I need to extract value of tag3

Any idea how this can be done ?

Comment: sorry for that, thanks, this actually worked !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=673caf03e477c6e85795bb290ec5e21b)

```
SELECT xpath('/tag1/tag2/tag3/text()', xmlcolumn)
```

[Postgres XML documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING)